# Prove that $f'(1)=0$ if $f(x^2)-\sin f(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb R$ such that:

$$f(x^2)-\sin f(x)=1 \quad \forall x\in\mathbb R$$

Prove that $f'(1)=0.$

**Attempt**:

I tried to differentiate and I got $$2xf'(x^2)-f'(x)\cos f(x)=0$$ then I put $x=1$ and I got $0=0$

I assume it is wrong.

Comment: Please show your effort..to provide extra context.

Comment: Taking the derivative of the equation, what do you get?

Comment: Differentiating both sides, we get that $$2xf'(x^2)-f'(x)\cos (f(x))=0$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,Yes I just corrected it.

Comment: @S.C.B. I would show it if I had any idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Differentiating
$$
2xf'(x^2)-f'(x)\cos(f(x))=0\ ,
$$
for all $x$.
Compute it for $x=1$
$$
2 f'(1)-f'(1)\cos(f(1))=0\Rightarrow f'(1)\left[2-\cos(f(1))\right]=0
$$
Now, $AB=0$ iff $A=0$ or $B=0$ [*zero-product property*]. So either $f'(1)=0$, or $\cos(f(1))=2$. But the cosine is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, so the only possibility is that $f'(1)=0$.

Comment: but you can factor out f(x) and f(x^2) if x = 1, as f(1)

Comment: Nicely done. (+1). Yeah, I meant it became untrue in general.

Comment: So I was getting there then... thank you very much

Comment: +1 liked that you also considered $2-\cos(f(1))$, sometimes is is easy to miss such details :).

Comment: Are we assuming that we cannot venture into the complex domain? Because if so $\cos^{-1} 2=-i\ln (2-\sqrt3)$